# bug in IPython history?

Tags: ipython

Is this a bug, or am I not understanding something about %hist in IPython?

```
In [79]: hist -g shapely
102/16: from shapely import Point, mapping
102/17: from shapely import Point, mapping
102/18: from shapely import mapping
102/19: import shapely
102/20: shapely?
140/53: import shapely
54: import shapely

In [80]: hist -n ~102/14-20
122/14: l
122/15: ls
122/16: nco.variables.keys()
122/17: ls
122/20: nco.sync()
```

Ok? There seems to be an offset of 20... Why?

```
In [81]: hist -n ~122/14-20
102/14: utm33N = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=33, south=False, ellipse='ED50')
102/15: import ogr
102/16: from shapely import Point, mapping
102/17: from shapely import Point, mapping
102/18: from shapely import mapping
102/19: import shapely
102/20: shapely?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it inverted, see the output of `%history?` for information about how to call it

The relevant bits:

> ```
> ``243/1-5``
>     Lines 1-5, session 243
> ``~2/7``
>     Line 7, session 2 before current
> ```

So `%history -n ~102/14-20` is actually lines 14-20 of 102 sessions *ago*.  For session 102, remove the tilde:

```
%history -n 102/14-20
```